# XULRunner Busy/Loading indicator

Tags: modal-dialog, xulrunner, busy-cursor

I have an XULRunner based application in which I need to (a) ask for user input using a custom dialog, and when the user clicks "OK", (b) perform the requested operation. This operation is an asynchronous operation on a server, and can take some time, so I would like to show a "loading" dialog or some form of busy indicator. I have tried to create a custom modal dialog that has a single label with "Please wait..." message, and close the dialog upon server reply; but server reply seems to be getting blocked while this modal dialog is open. Should I open the modal dialog in a certain way or run the operation in some kind of a thread so that the reply can be processed even while the modal dialog is open? I have tried to look up documentation, but couldn't find anything useful.  Appreciate any help from the stackoverflow community.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> server reply seems to be getting blocked while this modal dialog is open

This is not supposed to happen.

What XULRunner on what OS are you trying to use? How do you open a modal dialog? How do you interact with the server?

It would be best if you produced a simple testcase that can be used to reproduce the problem.